# OutOfMemory Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, out-of-memory

I tried to run the software tests already created in ellipse and now this error appears, any solution?

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
        logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        //Remove as mensagens do chromedriver na consola (e no output)

        System.out.println(String.format("%n%n", char.class));
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeInGMT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("--> Teste executado no dia --> " + dateTimeInGMT.format(new Date()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = "";
        try {
            String filename = "C:\\Eclipse\\eclipse\\fs.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true);
//          fw.write(dateTimeInGMT.format(new Date()));
            fw.close();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Eclipse\\eclipse\\fs.txt"));

            // read the file content
            while (str != null) {
                sb.append(str);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                str = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("starting");
        int tests = 0;
        int success = 0;
        int failed = 0;

        List<Pair<String, String>> faileds = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> testsNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        testsNames.add("UC2Login");
//      testsNames.add("UC5consultarPerfil");
//      testsNames.add("UC16CriarPaciente");

        for (String classi : testsNames) {

            try {
                System.out.println("runnnig " + classi);
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("casosUso." + classi);
                Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("start");
                Object d = c.newInstance();

                tests++;
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Pair<Boolean, String> result = (Pair<Boolean, String>) method.invoke(d);
                if (result.getKey()) {
                    success++;
                } else {
                    failed++;
                    faileds.add(new Pair<String, String>(classi, result.getValue()));
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n ==== REPORT ====");
        System.out.println(String.format("resume -> tests:%d success:%d failed:%d", tests, success, failed));
        for (Pair<String, String> pair : faileds) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s : %n%n", pair.getKey(), pair.getValue()));

        }

    }




       --> Teste executado no dia --> 27-mai-2019 11:36:20
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at casosUso.Main1.main(Main1.java:44)
```

Comment: You can increase the available heap. Or rework your code to not use so much heap.

As this occures on Arrays.copyOf, I guess, you try to copy a huge array. Maybe you can optimize the array, so it is smaller?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to post the main method from `Main1` so we can actually see what it's doing

Comment: The code is there

Comment: How big is `fs.txt`? If it's too big, you will need to either allocate more memory. or be smarter with how you read it.

Comment: I noticed now that the file already had a huge data volume and that's why it gave such an error. I deleted the data and ran again and it already works. What can I do to not have to clean the file?